# How do I play MP3s from my Dropbox?

Tags: music, mp3, dropbox, mp3-player

I have the [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) app on my Droid, and it can "download" files to the local storage on the phone, but for some reason, the music player app can't see those files.

How do I make the music playing app see the mp3s in my Dropbox? Is there an alternative way I should think about the problem or sync the files?

Answer (score 5):

In Dropbox, simply add MP3s to favorites and they become available in a stock Google Play Music application (Tested in Android ICS)

[image: Favorite]

Comment: That used to work for me, but after downloading the latest Dropbox, it no longer does. Now, even if I favorite an mp3 song on Dropbox and play it within the Dropbox app, it does not appear in my HTC phone's default music player nor Google Play Music.

Comment: I see. In this case, after tapping on a song it will be downloaded. Once it is saved, the Play Music app should see it.

Answer (score 3):

If you export the tunes to the SD card rather than the music app then they will show straight up in the music player. Just a little annoying that you've got to do them one at a time rather than as a group.

Dropbox > More > Export > Save to SD card > select Music folder

Answer (score 2):

[PowerAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) seems to be able to scan the file system automatically. At least when I opened it, all my offline available sound files (regardless of format, I have many WAV and M4A files) were playable, while the solution with RescanMedia (amongst others) didn't work.

The Android version is 5.0.1. Dropbox and PowerAmp are from 12/13/2015. It costs 4 Euros (there is a 15 day trial) but to me this is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more advanced music players have the ability to rescan media from the phone.

In [PlayerPro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tbig.playerpro) you can do Menu->Settings->Music Library->Refresh mediastore

This should then show up any music added since the last scan.

Comment: Hate to be the critic here but PlayerPro reports to no longer be able to Refresh the mediastore programmatically since 4.4 and will remove support for it (it would do that when media would be added to the sd card but I don't have one (yet) in my device...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en) on your Android device to sync your device with your music folder on Dropbox.

In Dropsync, you pair a folder on your device with a folder on Dropbox. You then choose from several options how those paired folders should sync.

I pair a Music folder on Dropbox with my device's default Music folder. In Dropsync, I use the 'Download mirror' setting, so that any changes I make on Dropbox (add songs, delete songs) sync to my device, but changes on my device won't affect my Dropbox folder.

The stock Google Music Player then watches my device's Music folder and updates the music library automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In dropbox just click the arrow on the right of the mp3 you want and use the "export" option and then save it to device. Done.

Comment: Indeed.  I would merely add that long-pressing a folder before export allows exporting all files in that folder at once.